# Illustrator: alignt according to points WITHIN object groups (not their uper/lower border or center)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

For example, I need to align graphs (i.e. groups of axis, data points, text labels etc.) vertically to their x or y axis, no matter how much space is consumed beyond (e.g. by yaxis labels, they may differ b/o number of digits, may be 2-lined etc) or above (e.g. by headings etc.). In the example, the x axis of the right plot would need to align to the yellow line extending the x axis of the first plot. Therefore, align to bottom/center/top is not useful. So far I use guides and place the graphs manually - works, but is somewhat laborous and prone to imprecision.
--> Is there a way to tell AI to exactly align the right plot according to a selected object (i.e .x axis, not the upper/lower border of the group) to another object (x axis of left graph) or guide? Thanks for any help!

This example is oversimplified example just for illustration, the real data graphs are much more complicated and less easy to handle manually. Dashed lines indicate borders of the object groups that apply if aligning to upper/lower/left/right border and illustrate that this is not helpful.

[image]

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no there's no feature or item which will auto-align to non-edge/center areas. Guides and snapping is about the only way.

Comment: if you use the white selection tool and select the entire other graph and then move by dragging a point on the x-axis. then you will be able to snap to a point on the other xaxis.

Comment: @joojaa: You mean the direct selection tool? Thanks, snapping works - at least in principle. But the problem is that there are too many lines/internal edges in both the "source" and "target" graph, and AI is really having a hard time to snap to the _intended_ object, i.e. there seems no preferential snapping to the point selected by the direct selection tool...

Comment: Snap it to a point then it prefers your point. then release and move with shift it back sideways.

Comment: Oh and one way is to hide all but the line you want to snap to (or copy in front and hide)

Comment: Ok, seems I'll have to continue to do this manually. Nevertheless thanks to Scott and joojaa!